# How to upload dependencies jar in lib folder in apigee from Edge UI

Tags: apigee

I created one jar file and in that i have class files, .classpath file, .project file In sample on github, i see apiproxy, callout and lib folder. when i deploy it, i getting error that traffic can't flow , i get error like traffic.How to upload dependencies jar in lib folder However when i upload my main jar file in resources folder, i don't see any lib folder for dependencies jars. Should i place all jars in one resources folder. in my .classpath file, i can see all lib jars like message-flow-1.0.0.jar, expressions-1.0.0.jar and itextpdf-5.5.6.jar. However in documentation, its given to deploy by maven but i don't know maven, from UI how should i create lib folder and upload jars there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in my understanding of your point.

1. You can upload jar file into apigee from **Scripts** > import file > in file type choose "JAR" > select jar file from your work space > and finally, define your jar name and then use policy **Java Callout** to call your jar.
2. If you have to modified your jar and want to deploy it, delete your existing jar in apigee and upload the new jar by following **1.** In case of new jar has the same name of existing jar, you do not need to do anything with Java Callout policy. But the new jar has the different name, don't forget to modified Java Callout for refer to your new jar.

Answer (score 0):

Please create the single jar file which contains jars like *message-flow-1.0.0.jar, expressions-1.0.0.jar and itextpdf-5.5.6.jar*. As per the apigee doc in create a **Java Callout** policy and make sure you have mentioned the package name & class name in Java Callout Poliy
    `<ClassName>package.ClassName</ClassName
    <ResourceURL>java://SingleJar.jar</ResourceURL>`